# Chose view to start for iPad and iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, addsubview

my first application that was just for the iPhone I decided to also implement the ability to be used on the iPad and the first thing I wanted to choose the view to use if it were in the opening of an iPhone or iPad, in my delegate I wrote :

```
NSString *devy = [[UIDevice currentDevice]model];
if ([devy isEqualToString:@"iPad"]) {
    [window addSubview:viewController.viewCpuIpad];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible]; 
} else {
    [window addSubview:viewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];    
}
```

When the iPhone's okay, but when I open it on the iPad only displays a blank screen .... where wrong?

thanks

Comment: Is `viewController.viewCpuIpad` blank?

Comment: viewCpuIpad is a UIView with more images and data.

Comment: i call code in method "- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application" of delegate

Comment: Have you tried logging information about it and `viewController`? Also try logging `devy` to see what it holds.

Comment: mmm in debug i read: "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch"

Comment: Don't use [[UIDevice currentDevice] model] to check if iPad or not.  Instead, use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple's recommended way (taken from Xcode's universal application project template) is:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

If you don't want to use IB, you can create your view in view controller's loadView method like:

```
- (void)loadView
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.view = // create view for iPad.
    } else {
        self.view = // create view for iPhone.
    }
}
```

(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() is a macro to support iOS 3.1 and earlier.)

Answer (score 0):

When you are launching in iPad, instead of calling,

**[window addSubview:viewController.viewCpuIpad];**

try like,

**viewController.view = viewCpuIPad;**

**[window addSubview:viewController.view];**

My suggestion is, you are not updating the viewController.view property when you are launching on iPad.

By Default, when you created the nib, the viewController.view is set to nib view which is displayed for iPhone.

For iPad, you are supposed to update this [viewcontroller view] property to your designated view. Else, as suggested by Hoshi, its also a good way to have two different Nib files so that you can load the required nib based on the condition.

Hopes this helps :)